# Read XML Config into PowerShell array

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, config

I'm trying to create a PS script that will read multiple file directories from an XML file and then depending on the filetype and date modified > 10 Days I want to delete the files.

I'm not sure how I should be accessing the config value so that i can setup a foreach loop. At the minute I have this in my script

```
#Read XML Config File to get settings
[xml]$configfile = Get-Content "C:\Project\TestForXML.xml"

#Declare and set variables from Config values
$dirs = @($configfile.Settings.DirectoryName)
$scanSubDirectories = $configfile.Settings.ScanSubDirectories
$deleteAllFiles = $configfile.Settings.deleteAllFiles
$fileTypesToDelete = $configfile.Settings.FileTypesToDelete
$liveSiteLogs = $configfile.Settings.LiveSiteLogs
$fileExclusions = $configfile.Settings.FileExclusions
$retentionPeriod = $configfile.Settings.RetentionPeriod
$aicLogs = $configfile.Settings.AICLogs
$aicLogsRententionPeriod = $configfile.Settings.AICLogsRententionPeriod

$Now = Get-Date -format d 
$Days = "10" 
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$retentionPeriod) 
$aicLastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$aicLogsRententionPeriod) 

$Logs = Get-Childitem $dirs -Include $fileTypesToDelete,$liveSiteLogs -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} 


foreach ($Log in $Logs) 
    { 
    Remove-Item $Log.FullName 
    $Msg =Write-Output "Deleting File $Log" 
    $Msg | out-file "C:\Desktop\Output.txt" -append 
    }
```

My XML Config files looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
<DirectoryName>"ServerA\C$\logs", "ServerB\C$\logfiles", 
               "ServerC\C$\logfiles", "ServerD\C$\logs"</DirectoryName>
<AICLogs>D:\DebugXML</AICLogs>
<AICLogsRententionPeriod>30</AICLogsRententionPeriod>
<ScanSubDirectories>True</ScanSubDirectories>
<DeleteAllFiles>False</DeleteAllFiles>
<FileTypesToDelete>.txt;.log;.mf</FileTypesToDelete>
<LiveSiteLogs>livesite.runtime.*</LiveSiteLogs> 
<FileExclusions>fdlogfile.log</FileExclusions>
<RetentionPeriod>13</RetentionPeriod>
```

Comment: Your XML config file is malformed, there is no closing `</Settings>` tag

Comment: Apologies my copy and paste didn't fully paste. the close </Settings> tag is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change out the following line.

```
$dirs = @($configfile.Settings.DirectoryName)
```

To something like this.

```
$dirs = @($configfile.Settings.DirectoryName.Split(",").Trim())
```

let me know if that gets you closer.